# os.walk() does not print out file and folder names

Tags: python, os.walk

```
import os
mypath = '/Users/ken/Desktop/myFolder/'

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(mypath): 
    print('The current folder is ' + folderName)
    
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder)
        
    for filename in filenames:
        print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName + ': '+ filename)
        
print('')
```

Hi guys, somehow my code above, which utilises the os.walk() function, does not print out anything at all. I'm pretty sure this is the correct way to state the path to my folder (which is indeed located on my desktop). However, when I tried to use the path '/Users/ken/' it does return and print out a whole bunch of files/folders. I'm not sure why with the above path (adding the /Desktop/myFolder) does not work. I am using a MacBook btw

Edit: I realised something else odd - in my home directory I have a Downloads folder as well which stores all my recent downloads from online. Somehow when I set the path as `/Users/ken/Downloads` it prints nothing out as well. It does work for any other `/Users/ken/anyfolder` contained in my home directory though but I'm not sure why it doesn't access my folders on my Desktop

Edit: It works when I tried it on another text editor (PyCharm). Previously I tried it on mu-editor. Idk why it doesn't work

Comment: The path is absolute, it should start from root: `r"C:\Users\ken\Desktop\myFolder\"`
Edit: slashes going the other way can also be used `"C:/Users/ken/Desktop/myFolder"`

Comment: I'm using a mac, so I don't have to include C: in front isn't it?

Comment: If this code prints nothing at all, then `/Users/ken/Desktop/myFolder/` must not exist.

Comment: @AAAlex123 He said `/Users/ken/` worked, so I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: I am absolutely certain '/Users/ken/Desktop/myFolder/' exists, I created this folder just to test this code out

Comment: Does it actually print `Downloads` and `Desktop` when you try at `'/Users/ken/' `? I don't have mac but chances are they are just shortcuts.

Comment: Hm i included an if statement to only print out `if folderName == 'Desktop' or folderName == 'Downloads'` and commented out the other 2 for loops to only print out the root. Unfortunately no it does not print anything out. How would I go about this if I wish to access a folder on my desktop then? 

I tried using the same path to, for example, `os.makedirs('/Users/ken/Desktop/newFolder') and it does work in this sense though?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen yeah I think that's it. For some reason no error is printed when the path is not found. If you try `os.chdir("/Users/ken/Desktop/myFolder/")` you should see `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: Can you start terminal from file explorer? Then run something like `pwd` should prints out what your directory actually named

Comment: From terminal, I am able to do `cd /Users/ken/Desktop/myFolder`. That should mean that the path does exist right?

Comment: And pwd there gives you `/Users/ken/Desktop/myFolder`?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen yeah it does!

Comment: `print(os.listdir('/Users/ken'))` should gives you all the names possible. Maybe python just read it differently?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen when I do that, I do see both the directories Desktop and Downloads . Still not sure why my code doesn't work

Comment: Wait, is the `myFolder` empty?

Comment: And does `os.listdir('/Users/ken/Desktop')`  work?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen In the root folder myFolder, I have another subfolder and a random text file. In the subfolder, I have another text file too. And yes `os.listdir('/Users/ken/Desktop')` does work, I can see myFolder in the list too. This is so weird

Comment: Ok I actually tried it on another text editor (PyCharm) and it works now. Idk why it doesn't work on the initial editor I used (mu-editor)

Comment: This is a very good question. As far as I can see it is unanswered. It deserves more upvotes and also good answers

Answer (score 0):

well you can use other functions such as lsdir and chdir;
they are flexible to use.

Comment: The problem is those folders have different names than what they're suppose to be.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately os.walk does not throw the associated error message. You should try os.listdir which would give you back a message saying: "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted". Most likely you are not the administrator on the machine or you would not have been given the right privileges. You might be thinking you should (by default) be given access to the Desktop or the Download folders. Unfortunately that does not happen. In my case I had access only to the root folder of my username. So please go ahead and create a Dev directory in 'Users/Ken' directly and it will work. Alternatively please work with your administrator to get complete drive access to all folders under Settings/Privacy.

Answer (score 0):

set this as a PATH

mypath = 'c:\Users\ken\Desktop\myFolder\'

I don't know if it would show, but there are two left slashes \\ between the folder names